# $x=r\cosφ, y=r\sinφ$, how to calculate $\dfrac{\partial φ}{\partial x}$?

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

One approach I see is
[one approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZjVy.png)

But what if I just put the expression $x=r\cosφ$ on the $\partial x$, it gives $\dfrac{-1}{r\sin φ}$, so which is wrong?

Comment: $$x=r\cos{\varphi}$$
than
$$\partial_{x}x=\partial_{x}(r\cos{\varphi})$$
$$1=(\partial_{x}r)\cos{\varphi}-r\sin{\varphi}\partial_{x}\varphi$$
$$\partial_{x}r=\partial_{x}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=\frac{x}{r}$$
Thus
$$1=\frac{x\cos{\varphi}}{r}-r\sin{\varphi}\partial_{x}\varphi=\cos^{2}{\varphi}-r\sin{\varphi}\partial_{x}\varphi$$
$$1-\cos^{2}{\varphi}=\sin^{2}{\varphi}=-r\sin{\varphi}\partial_{x}\varphi$$
Thus
$$\partial_{x}\varphi=-\frac{\sin{\varphi}}{r}$$

Comment: *"what if I just put the expression x=rcosφ on the ∂x"*: I have no idea what this is supposed to mean

Comment: I think ∂r*cosφ=-rsinφ∂φ, because in the question r is a fixed value

Comment: Putting "$x = r\cos\varphi$ on the $\partial x$" is wrong; $r$ depends on $x$.

Comment: I understand, thanks!

Comment: Although you may have gotten away with treating ordinary derivatives as fractions, it *really* doesn’t work for partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}x&=\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}r-r\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
\mathrm{d}y&=\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}r+r\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}\varphi
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$
$(1)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}x&=\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}r-r\sin^2(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}y&=\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}r+r\cos^2(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}\varphi
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
and subtracting the equations of $(2)$ gives
$$
-\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}x+\cos(\varphi)\,\mathrm{d}y=r\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\tag{3}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}
&=-\frac{\sin(\varphi)}r\\
&=-\frac y{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$